# Extract 301 Redirect URL from Google Sheets - Script Editor

Tags: google-sheets, extract

I've been looking a way to improve an awesome Google Sheets Script I found on StackOverflow:

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

It ends up giving you the status (200, 301, 500, 404, etc), However I want to extract the URL in case there is a redirect.

Does anyone know what should I add on the script, I'm not that savy on the matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse Shortened URL to Get the Original URL Before the Shortening in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324526/reverse-shortened-url-to-get-the-original-url-before-the-shortening-in-google-sh)